# RavenDB map reduce, duplicate entries in reduce

Tags: mapreduce, ravendb

I have created a map function in Raven that looks like this

```
from order in docs.WebOrderModels
 from orderLine in order.OrderLines
 where order.OrderStatus.OrderStatusId == 3
 select new{
    orderLine.Sku,
    orderLine.Quantity
 }
```

together with the following reduce

```
from result in results
 group result by new {result.Sku, result.Quantity} into g
 select new{
     Sku = g.Key.Sku,
     Quantity = g.Sum(x => x.Quantity)
 }
```

Running this mostly work, except that I get dupliacate entries for the Sku, See the image: [image]

The same Sku number appears two times.
When I look through the data there does not seem to be any difference other than the quantities per order object.
I have tried to make two new order objects to see if happens when two order objects contains orderlines for the same sku number. But they are added together as I would expect.

I can't find any reason why the two entries are not reduced to one entry.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are grouping the result with:

```
group result by new {result.Sku, result.Quantity} into g
```

which will give you result entries **per different (Sku & Quantity) pairs**

Use

```
group result by result.Sku
```

See:
https://demo.ravendb.net/demos/csharp/static-indexes/map-reduce-index#step-4